# Typescript Dynamic Module Import throws an error

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to import module dynamically.

`consumers.ts`

```
if (condition) {
    import("src/app/apis/mocks/consumer-list.dev");
}
```

but the code above throws the following error:

`Cannot find module 'src/app/apis/mocks/consumer-list.dev'`

at the same time when I use non-dynamic import for the same path, everything goes fine

```
import { consumers } from "src/app/apis/mocks/consumer-list.dev";
```

1. why the dynamic import fails?
2. what I need to do to make it work?

typescript version:2.9.2

the structure of modules:

```
------src
--------app
----------apis
-------------mocks
-----------------consumer-list.dev.ts
-------------consumers.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Wich version of typescript do you have ? (import supported since TypeScript 2.4.)
try to use a relative ./  a start of your path.

```
const module = './src/app/apis/mocks/consumer-list.dev';
```

import function is synchronised and returns a Promise.

```
 import('module').then(e => {
        consol.log(e);
    });
```

Comment: the version of typescript is 2.9.2.
adding ./ at start doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I see your consumers.ts from where the call is trigger, is under maock where it containt de module.

So try `./mocks/consumer-list.dev`

Comment: the same result: Error: Cannot find module './mocks/consumer-list.dev'

Answer (score 0):

Finally found what was causing the problem:

I used variable for module name:

```
const mock = "src/app/apis/mocks/consumer-list.dev"
import(mock)
```

At the same time the following code would run:

```
import("src/app/apis/mocks/consumer-list.dev")
```

It's how webpack handles dynamic import. And here is github issue with workaround:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6680